# accessing values from two private classes java

Tags: java

I'm a straight noob at Java but I guess I have to start somewhere. I have two jSliders and I want to get the value from both of them when a checkbox is clicked next to them. Then I want to take this value and add it together in a separate class.

How do I call the private class into the addvalues class?

```
private void jCheckBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
   if (jCheckBox1.isSelected() == true){
        int value1 = jSlider3.getValue();
    }
    else
    {
        int value1 = 0;
    } 
}          

private void jCheckBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
     if (jCheckBox2.isSelected() == true){
        int value2 = jSlider1.getValue();
    }
    else
    {
        int value2 = 0;
    } 
}                                          

public void addvalues() {

jCheckBox1ActionPerformed();
jCheckBox2ActionPerformed();

//code for addition

value = value1 + value2;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where are you stuck? Please help us out here so that we can understand what's wrong and try to figure out how to help.

Comment: I apologize, I updated the question.

Comment: But not enough it seems. Please put just a little more effort into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create another class "AdderClass" with two private int's, a constructor `public AdderClass(int value1, int value2)` (in which you set the class's private ints to value1 and value2), and  move the method "addvalues()" to the "AdderClass".

Then in the main class create an "AdderClass" object with the values of the two checkboxes, and do `adderObject.addvalues();`

Answer (score 1):

You don't call the actionPerformed methods in the addValues method, since these methods are called by events and are almost never called directly by you the coder. Instead simply query both JSlider values when the JCheckBox is checked.

You've not clarified your class structure enough for me to guess what you mean by:

> Then I want to take this value and add it together in a separate class.

Also you state that you don't know how to call a `"private class"` without explaining just what you mean by this, and I have a strong feeling that you're using incorrect terminology since the only private classes I know of are private inner classes, and I'm pretty sure that you didn't mean these.

Again you need to post more clarification and code.